# VB Now.Ticks equiv in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, date

How can I replicate this in javascript?

```
Now.Ticks.ToString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pleasant, but here's your answer:
http://codemonkey.joeuser.com/article/308527

[`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) represent the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1st, 0001.

JavaScript has `Date.getTime()` which measures the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, so if you're just after something that's unique then you could use that.  Obviously that's not directly comparable to `DateTime.Ticks` though.

Comment: @Oppdal It's not a nightmare... It's just addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 8):

There is no real equivalent. You ask two questions:

1. How do I get the current date & time in javascript? This is easy, just write

   ```
   var now = new Date();
   ```
2. How do I get the number of ticks since Januari 1, 0001? This one is harder, because javascript doesn't work with ticks, but with milliseconds, and the offset is Januari 1, 1970 instead.

   You can start with `now.getTime()` to get the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, and then multiply this with 10000. I just calculated the number of ticks between 0001-01-01 and 1970-01-01, and this is 621355968000000000. If you also take into account the timezone, the resulting code looks like this:

   ```
   function getTicks(date)
   {
       return ((date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) * 10000) + 621355968000000000;
   }
   ```

Now `getTicks(new Date())` will get the same result as `Now.Ticks.ToString` in VB.Net with an error margin of 1 millisecond.

Comment: Much less complicated (and obvious) answer that the accepted answer.  One simple easy to explain expression instead of a complicated translation.

Answer (score 4):

```
var date = new Date();
var ticks = date.getTime();
```

getTime returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970

Comment: It is relevant to note that this is not equivalent to ticks, which are smaller than milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond` for your ticks if accuracy is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest, simplest version would be...

```
//get string version of time to the nearest millisecond
var now = "" + new Date().getTime();

//Though in most cases its easier to keep it as a number, and just concatinate in your output somewhere
document.title = "Now it is: " + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: because this question was tagged vb.net, and vb.net has a 'strong' language hint, this is being highlighted as vb.net. Just FYI. You must use language overrides. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82032/please-add-prettyprint-class-when-explicitly-defined-class-with-language/82042#82042

Comment: Hmm, I get "why" now... but I'm seeing this as more of a "regression" in usability than a "feature" (since it seemed to just work before).  The question is also tagged javascript (and in this case the desired answers are javascript).  Is there an order in which tagged questions apply prettifying?

Comment: then you should remove the [vb.net] tag from this question